# Did Roger Ailes say "the truth is whatever people will believe" or something substantially similar?

Tags: quotes, media

The below image popped up on Facebook apparently alleging that Roger Ailes, president of the Fox News Channel, said:

> "The truth" is whatever people will believe.

[image: Roger Ailes alleged quote]

The peculiar placement of the quote marks makes it unclear whether this is intended as a direct quote attributed to Roger Ailes or is just commentary.

Google reveals that [Joseph Heller](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Joseph_Heller#God_Knows_.281984.29) said something very much like this in his 1984 book *God Knows*:

> "The truth is whatever people will believe is the truth. Don't you know history?"

But I can find no reference to Roger Ailes having said this, or anything substantially similar.

Comment: Sounds bit like paraphrased *Consensus gentium*, which is rather ancient concept (as old as Plato's works or older).

Comment: This doesn't make any assertions to this claim, but on a similar vein, [Fox News did go to court for the right of news media to lie](http://www.projectcensored.org/top-stories/articles/11-the-media-can-legally-lie/).  I am doubtful this is a direct quote from Ailes but I wouldn't be surprised in light of this.

Comment: " Fox News did go to court for the right of news media to lie" is a huge oversimplification of that case.

Comment: statements similar to this are pretty common, ["When the legend becomes fact, print the legend"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056217/quotes) from 1962. If he did say something like that it could easily be taken out of context, and even if it wasn't its not exactly a rarity for people to say things like that. "never let the facts get in the way of ..." is also of similar sentiment and is reasonably common.

Comment: @maple_shaft - since that claim has been [thoroughly debunked](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/25217/did-fox-news-win-a-court-case-for-the-right-to-lie?lq=1), I'd appreciate it if you removed your misleading comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely he did not. There's no direct evidence (because it's impossible to prove the negative and there's no exhaustive "collection of 100% of things Ailes ever said in print or orally" like there's for someone like George Washington).

Nevertheless, the evidence seems to be on the debunking side:

1. Most of the time the claim is posted, it's posted with zero details or evidence (e.g. no citation or details of attribution).

   I verified this by following every single link from the first 4 Google pages searching for the quote (there were [only 40 search results for me](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20truth%22%20is%20whatever%20people%20will%20believe.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22The%20truth%20is%20whatever%20people%20will%20believe%22&start=30)).
2. The ONLY times any details are provided, they are "he said it in 1984 book" ([Example](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6079613591)).

   Well, THAT specific claim can be tested... and is ***false***.

   That specific quote **can** be found in a 1984 book. Except, it was in a book "[God Knows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Knows_%28novel%29)" by Joseph Heller, (more well known as the author of "Catch-22"), as can be found on [WikiQuote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Joseph_Heller).

   > The truth is whatever people will believe is the truth. Don't you know history?

   On the contrary, Ailes' listed [Bibliography on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Ailes#Bibliography) has no 1984 books.

Comment: In short, as Abraham Lincoln said, "don't believe everything you see on Internet"

Comment: Thanks for the research. I'm willing to accept this answer, on the (probably permanently) tentative understanding that if evidence is ever found to the contrary, I may reverse my acceptance of this answer. :)